# NVIDIA driver 331 recent update breaks Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10

I just recovered from Nvidia driver failure after an update was pushed a few hours ago from Xedger ppa. There is not much insight from what I can search from the web. Currently, my system is running on Nouveau but this means a no-go for steam games.....

my gpu is GTX 650 TI

I'm still fairly new to Linux and I'm not sure what is the next step. Any suggestions? Should I wait for some time before trying to install it again?

Comment: Sorry, just discovered that too

Comment: sory for my english. my opinion it is a bug on update from ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/399560/bug-nvidia-drivers-after-update check if you have in etc a folder Bumblebee an /etc/modprobe.d/ Bumblebee.conf

Comment: Hi, I did not find the .conf file.  However, if you mean if Bumblebee was installed when things go crazy, then yes. At first I only purged nvidia related package but it wasn't helpful until I uninstalled bumblebee. This is also a part that I don’t understand.. I had previously disabled Intel graphics in the BIOS so that I can use the nvidia driver. THe question is why bumblebee was installed since the system should only see one graphics card..... of course there is still a lot of things on Linux that I dont know of.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add
nvidia_331
to /etc/modules
for unknown reasons the modul aliasing is not working for nvidia